# How to retrieve value of constraint from Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

Say I have a constraint that is defined in the following way in my abstractmodel:

```
def flow_constraint(model, t, b):
flows = sum(
            sum( (model.Factor[area_from, t, b] - model.Factor[area_to, t, b]) 
                * model.flow[area_from, area_to, t] for (area_to) in get_border(area_from))
                    for area_from in model.Areas)
return flows <= model.RAM[t, b] 

model.flow_constraint = Constraint(model.BranchesIndex, rule = flow_constraint)
```

Is there a way to retrieve the value of this constraint directly from the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraint values only make sense in the context of a concrete instance.  For abstract models, the constraints have been *declared* but not *defined*.  That is, the containers (like Constraint) have been declared to exist, but they are empty.  Once you have a concrete instance (either after calling `create_instance()` on the Abstract model or by directly creating a ConcreteModel), there are a couple options.

Your constraint is really a set of constraints (indexed by `model.BranchesIndex`).  You can *display* the values of all the constraints in the indexed constraint with:

```
# (assuming m is a concrete instance from create_instance(), or a ConcreteModel)
m.flow_constraint.display()
```

You can get the numerical values of a single constraint through the `lower`, `body`, and `upper` attributes.  For example:

```
print("%s <= %s <= %s" % ( 
    value(m.flow_constraint[t,b].lower),
    value(m.flow_constraint[t,b].body),
    value(m.flow_constraint[t,b].upper) ))
```